# Issue with multiple star rating

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a star rating application where users can vote between 1 and 5.but now its allow only single rating ie if I select stars from second, the first section seems select instead of second(always defaults the first section ). I tried to change class and id, but it didn't work.

Html code:

```
<fieldset id='demo1' class="rating">
   <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star_a-5" name="rating" value="5" />
   <label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
   <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star_a_5-half" name="rating" value="4.5" />
   <label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
   <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star_a-4" name="rating" value="4" />
   <label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
   <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star_a_4-half" name="rating" value="3.5" />
   <label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
   <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star_a-3" name="rating" value="3" />
   <label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
   <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star_a_3-half" name="rating" value="2.5" />
   <label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
   <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
   <label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
   <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1.5" />
   <label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
   <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
   <label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
   <input class="stars" type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="0.5" />
   <label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>    
</div>
<br><br><br>
<p><strong>2. Productivity </strong>- the extent to which the employee's behaviors are directed toward fostering positive
                working relationships in a diverse workplace, respect for one's fellow workers, and cooperation with students,
                customers, and visitors. </p>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="comment">Comments:</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <fieldset id='demo2' class="rating">
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
      <label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4.5" />
      <label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
      <label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3.5" />
      <label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
      <label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2.5" />
      <label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
      <label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1.5" />
      <label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
      <label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="0.5" />
      <label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
   </fieldset>    
</div>
<br><br><br> 
<p><strong>3. Work Quality </strong> - the extent to which the employee contributes to the effectiveness of the
                department and the overall mission of the university. (NOTE: Time off approved under FMLA may not be
                considered)  </p>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="comment">Comments: :</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <fieldset id='demo3' class="rating">
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
      <label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4.5" />
      <label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
      <label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3.5" />
      <label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
      <label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2.5" />
      <label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
      <label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1.5" />
      <label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
      <label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
      <input class="stars" type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="0.5" />
      <label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
   </fieldset>    
</div>
<br><br><br>
```

css:

```
 <style>
    /****** Rating Starts *****/
    @import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

    fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    body{ margin: 20px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }
    .rating { 
       border: none;
       float: left;
    }
    .rating > input { display: none; } 
    .rating > label:before { 
       margin: 5px;
       font-size: 1.25em;
       font-family: FontAwesome;
       display: inline-block;
       content: "\f005";
    }
    .rating > .half:before { 
       content: "\f089";
       position: absolute;
    }
    .rating > label { 
       color: #ddd; 
       float: right; 
    }
    .rating > input:checked ~ label, 
       .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,  
       .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;
    }
    .rating > input:checked + label:hover, 
       .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
       .rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, 
       .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;
    }     
    /* Downloaded from http://devzone.co.in/ */
</style>
```

js:

```
<script>
   $('document').ready(function () {
      $('.toggleswitch').bootstrapToggle();
      $("#demo1 .stars").click(function () { 
         alert($(this).val());
         $(this).attr("checked");
      });
      $("#demo2 .stars").click(function () { 
         alert($(this).val());
         $(this).attr("checked");
      });
      $("#demo3.stars").click(function () { 
         alert($(this).val());
         $(this).attr("checked");
      });
   });
</script>
```

Please help me. how can i solve this issue?

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `Id`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen-i am totally new to jquery..please help me

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I changed your errors and also made your jQuery a bit more simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had multiple problems in your HTML:

1. You had multiple elements with the same `id`, never have more than 1 element with the same `id` on a page.
2. All your `radio's` had the same `name` attribute value. So that's why if you click on the first rating it would remove any rating on rating 2 or 3

I've also changed your `jQuery` to make it a more simple. Basically i changed this: `$("fieldset[id^='demo'] .stars")` Now it takes all `fieldset` that have an `id` that starts with `demo`

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.toggleswitch').bootstrapToggle();
  $("fieldset[id^='demo'] .stars").click(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
    $(this).attr("checked");
  });
});
```

```css
/****** Rating Starts *****/

@import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);
fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 10px;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating>input:checked~label,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/js/bootstrap-toggle.js"></script>
<fieldset id='demo1' class="rating">
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="1star_a-5" name="1rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="1star_a-5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="1star_a_5-half" name="1rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1star_a_5-half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="1star_a-4" name="1rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="1star_a-4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="1star_a_4-half" name="1rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1star_a_4-half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="1star_a-3" name="1rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="1star_a-3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="1star_a_3-half" name="1rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1star_a-3-half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="1star2" name="1rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="1star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="1star2half" name="1rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1star2half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="1star1" name="1rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="1starhalf" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>

</div>
<br><br><br>
<strong>2. Productivity </strong>- the extent to which the employee's behaviors are directed toward fostering positive working relationships in a diverse workplace, respect for one's fellow workers, and cooperation with students, customers, and visitors.
</p>



<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Comments:
                        :</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <fieldset id='demo2' class="rating">
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="2star_a-5" name="2rating" value="5" />
    <label class="full" for="2star_a-5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="2star_a_5-half" name="2rating" value="4.5" />
    <label class="half" for="2star_a_5-half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="2star_a-4" name="2rating" value="4" />
    <label class="full" for="2star_a-4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="2star_a_4-half" name="2rating" value="3.5" />
    <label class="half" for="2star_a_4-half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="2star_a-3" name="2rating" value="3" />
    <label class="full" for="2star_a-3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="2star_a_3-half" name="2rating" value="2.5" />
    <label class="half" for="2star_a-3-half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="2star2" name="2rating" value="2" />
    <label class="full" for="2star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="2star2half" name="2rating" value="1.5" />
    <label class="half" for="2star2half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="2star1" name="2rating" value="1" />
    <label class="full" for="2star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="2starhalf" name="2rating" value="0.5" />
    <label class="half" for="2starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
  </fieldset>

</div>
<br><br><br>


<strong>3. Work Quality </strong> - the extent to which the employee contributes to the effectiveness of the department and the overall mission of the university. (NOTE: Time off approved under FMLA may not be considered) </p>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Comments:
                        :</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <fieldset id='demo3' class="rating">
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="3star_a-5" name="3rating" value="5" />
    <label class="full" for="3star_a-5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="3star_a_5-half" name="3rating" value="4.5" />
    <label class="half" for="3star_a_5-half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="3star_a-4" name="3rating" value="4" />
    <label class="full" for="3star_a-4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="3star_a_4-half" name="3rating" value="3.5" />
    <label class="half" for="3star_a_4-half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="3star_a-3" name="3rating" value="3" />
    <label class="full" for="3star_a-3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="3star_a_3-half" name="3rating" value="2.5" />
    <label class="half" for="3star_a-3-half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="3star2" name="3rating" value="2" />
    <label class="full" for="3star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="3star2half" name="3rating" value="1.5" />
    <label class="half" for="3star2half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="3star1" name="3rating" value="1" />
    <label class="full" for="3star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="3starhalf" name="3rating" value="0.5" />
    <label class="half" for="3starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
  </fieldset>

</div>
<br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your ids are repeating. Rename it.
Check id = "star2half" in demo1

```
<input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2.5" />
<label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
```

demo 3 :

```
<input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2.5" />
<label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
```

Comment: There are more problems than just the `id`'s ,  so you answer only solves some of the problems